# Determine if an array will generate the same BST provided - Use Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, search, tree, binary

I have a problem that I am running into a few issues with, the question is as follows:

`Given a pre-constructed Binary Search Tree and an array, determine if the array will produce the same Binary Search Tree.`

Now, this question will have a pre-constructed BST for you, and then it will run through the following code:

```
boolean valid = true;
for (int i = 0;valid && i < arr.length; i ++) {
   valid &= tree.checkPattern(arr[i]);
}

//These two methods below are in a different class. For every element in the array,
//the checkPattern method will be called, initially passing in the root of the BST
public void checkPattern(int key) {
   recursiveFunction(root, key);
}

public boolean recursiveFunction(TreeNode current, int key){
 // Recursive function 
}
```

The goal is to write the`recursiveFunction(root, arr[i])`, and a hint is that the TreeNode class contains a `visited` boolean that you are to use to help with this algorithm.

I can't quite seem to figure out how to solve this... Given a key, are you supposed to check to see where it would go in the primary BST, and if the parent has already been visited, then return false?

Comment: My teacher used (for a BFS algorithm) a step/weight 1/2D (depends on the map type) array. This array simply was full of integer values (filled with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as a default for convenience) which was the cost of getting there, and the code would check if it were more efficient to walk over it this way, or the previously found way.

Comment: @FailingCoder What does BFS (Breadth-First Search) have to do with searching a BST (**Binary** Search Tree)? In a BST, you can walk down the tree directly to the node you're looking for, only stepping on one node per level. BFS and DFS (Depth-First Search) is about walk through every node in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to build a new BST from the array, then compare the two trees. Think about how that builds the tree one node at a time.

Now, with a `visited` flag in every node, we start with all the flags being false, then the logic is:

- For each value in the array, look for the node for that value (the target node) in the tree:

  - If the target node is not found, then answer is no (tree and array have different values).
  - If the path to the target node steps on any node that has not been visited yet, then answer is no (wrong order).
  - *(optional)* If the target node has already been visited, throw `IllegalArgumentException` (duplicate values in array not allowed).
  - Mark the target node visited.
- Scan the tree (BFS or DFS, doesn't matter), and if you find any unvisited node, then answer is no (tree and array have different values).
- If you get here, answer is yes.

Comment: Follow-up question for you, Andreas.

Regarding the last two points in your logic tree, does this only apply if you have a BST with more nodes than the array could generate? (i.e. it would always be false, cause the number of nodes is different)

I am having trouble finding an edge case where we would ever hit that point in the logic otherwise - because if you hit a node that has not been visited previously, you are returning false, otherwise, you assume you are on the right path.

Comment: @Bergis If you allow duplicates in the array (e.g. you don't do the optional step), then number of values in the array may be larger than number of nodes in the tree, so don't rely on count to know if there are extra values in array and/or tree.